# Animating View.scrollTo(...)

Tags: android

How to implement scrolling animation?
I'm ok with setting a simple AlphaAnimation that triggers at scrollTo(...) but what kind of animation is required for one screen to replace another in a sophisticated manner?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but to allow for swiping across views, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation1 - scrollTo() - Animation2

Comment: Hi, @alex, would you please be more specific on how this is done? I am also trying to animate `scrollTo()`, but it looks like Android has no built in solutions.