# Android Navigation Bar Top

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

How can i make a Navigation Bar at the top of my application? I would like something like the top bar in the photo:
[link text](http://blog.podgrove.com/iph-1.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is pretty similar, and might be what you're looking for: [Android / layout: how to create a header-content layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002920/android-layout-how-to-create-a-header-content-layout).

As far as creating the header, simply create a `RelativeLayout` with two `Buttons`: one attached to the parent's left and one to the parent's right.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a customized header place this code in your application tag in manifest file to hide default tab bar

```
<Application
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" <!--
other parameters of application tag-->
>
```

and the then