# Navigation bar in relative layout (Android App)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have made an `Activity` with `RelativeLayout` and has been set well. Now as per the new requirement I have to add a navigation drawer to top left corner. How can I proceed further? Please anyone explain briefly.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cyNs6.png) is navigation bar. Are you sure you want to add that to the top left corner? I would suggest to read about android [design patterns](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/app-structure.html) so you can describe your problems clearly :)

Comment: Yes sorry I misused the name, its navigation drawer I need to add. The hamburger icon on top left corner. In my relative layout I have text view, edit view and image view. Now if I replace the <relative layout> tag with <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> tag I lose my edit view and I cant even drag and drop it. So i believe I have to use relative layout if I want to contain edit view in my activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Navigation Bar Top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184778/android-navigation-bar-top)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `NavigationView` to create your drawer. All you need to do is just to wrap your current `RelativeLayout` in the `DrawerLayout` and add the `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Note you have to create your menu under `res/menu/drawer.xml`. You alsou should use `AppCompatActivity` and set your `Toolbar` with `setSupportActionBar()`.

[This](http://blog.xebia.com/2015/06/09/android-design-support-navigationview/) is relatively good tutorial. [This one](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) is even more detailed.

Comment: thank you. I tried wrapping up my relative view in drawable. Which made no change in existing design.